# Centos 6.6 not booting on Virtualbox on Windows host

Tags: centos, windows, virtualbox

I downloaded the QuickStart VM from Cloudera that has preinstalled Spark/Hadoop etc. I have been working on that for the last 4-5 weeks and it was running absolutely fine, but recently I had to restart my VM. Since, then the VM does not restart. It shows the loading bar but after that it seems as if it stopped responding. It only shows a small black screen and does not go anywhere from there.

[image]

When I press Alt-Tab the screen changes to 
[image]

I cannot understand what has gone wrong?
Here are a few things that I have evaluated till now.

- I am not able to login using Single User Mode. I think the user `cloudera` is not found. As a result of which I am not able to access any file that I made as that user.
- This led me to check the partitions that I had. The size of my Virtual Disk is 100GB but when I tried to open it on [VMXray](http://www.vmxray.com/) I noticed that the disk showed only around 65GB. All the files/folder/applications that I had as `cloudera` were missing.
- I can only login using the `emergency` mode where I can see all my installations that I did as the root.

Comment: Just a tip: for virtual machines it's a good idea to have one console display the system log, i.e. tty12. Have you regularly checked free space on yours? Otherwise you can always import the virtual disk into another VM and check from there. Also: press the «*Esc*» key as soon as the progress bar appears as the machine starts, it'll show the startup log.

Comment: I increased my VM size by ~30GB. The second image is the one that I get after pressing `Esc` key. It remains stuck after that.

Comment: What do you mean with «*increased my VM size by ~30GB*» ? Did you increase the VM's file systems as well? It's not enough to just increase the virtual disk size, the file systems on it need to also be resized (i.e. increased). But that requires either logging into the virtual machine (which is not possible ATM) or attaching the disk to another VM and increase this one's file systems from there.

Comment: I used `Gparted` to increase size of the FileSystems as well. I initially had aroung 60 GB where ~40 GB was full. Now I have increased it to ~100 GB. The boot stucks @ `Setting up Logical Volume Management: 3 logical volume(s) in volume group "Vol Group" now active`

Comment: Obviously your virtual machine is running on a Logical Volume Manager (LVM). Please make sure you understand [how to resize LVM volumes](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/extending-lvm). You still need to determine *if* and *which* volume(s) get filled before expanding anything.

Comment: But I got this problem before I had resized it. I resized when you earlier mentioned about free space on my system!!

Comment: Without more info any accurate help is hard to impossible. Did you upgrade VirtualBox recently? If yes, then [this blog article](https://believeinmiraclesx.wordpress.com/2014/01/14/centos-stuck-at-boot-screen-progress-bar/) might help.

Comment: There is nothing that I have explicitly done. I have been running this VM for the last one month. There was no such issue. When today I restarted it, I have been having this issue. Yes, I had upgraded my VBox but it was like more than a couple of weeks back. I tried what is given but still it is stuck @ the same point. Is there anything else I should be telling?

Comment: Well, first off, nothing tells if you know how a GNU/Linux machine works, CentOS in particular, so I can't assume you do. Nothing tells if you have regularly monitored file system growth on your virtual machine. Can't assume that either. (On what system did you run Gparted, BTW?) So first is to access your virtual machine's main log file: `/var/log/messages` to determine the cause of the issue, including *if* it is a file system being full, which was my first comment's point.

Comment: I ran `Gparted` on VBox with Win8 Host. I have used to resize two other VMs that I have. So it worked out fine. I am using the VM provided my Cloudera that has 63 GB disk-space where I had used a total of 40 GB. I am trying to access the log files by Single User login as suggested but again the cosole seems to hang at the same point.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean by «ran Gparted on VBox with Win8 Host». Are you saying you accessed your VM's virtual disk contents directly from the host? If yes I suppose you know the VM must be powered off before hand. Anyway you should be able to access the VM's logs by booting it with a live CD from any GNU/Linux distribution. Then mount the filesystem that contains `/var` and check it from that mount point.

Comment: I know that. The VM was powered off. I have resized VMs plenty of times and even this time everything worked fine.

Comment: I have made some edits. See if they help.

Comment: As for disk space, and if you can log on at least in emergency mode the *only* relevant result is that of command `df -h` when run *from* the virtual machine itself. This is the only way to tell if the virtual machine has enough free space. Also post the contents of your virtual machine's `/etc/fstab` and make sure all the file systems are properly mounted by running `mount`. Append the results to your question.

Comment: For me, installing the Guest Additions fixed the problem. I followed the link given by @user86969, https://believeinmiraclesx.wordpress.com/2014/01/14/centos-stuck-at-boot-screen-progress-bar/